# Kernel Panic after repartitioning disk with gparted

Tags: uefi, gparted, kernel-panic

I have a Dell Inspiron 5523, which has two drives. One is an HDD (call it sda) and one an SSD (call it sdb). My system is dual boot UEFI with a large part of it being Windows 8 (around 332GB) and a the rest Linux Mint (72GB).

My system had a swap space on sdb and on sda I have two partitions: sda9  has all the system files and sda10 has the home folder files. Recently, I wanted to pass some space from sda9 to sda10 because the first was set up with 60GB and the second with only 7.7GB. So I used gparted live CD and moved 30 GB from sda9 to sda10.

After the procedure finished with no problem, when rebooting again and choosing the Linux Mint Cinammon option, I got a kernel panic printing the following:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode:0x00007f00

CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: sh Not tainted 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Call Trace:
dump_stack +0x45/0x56
panic+0xc8/0x1fc
do_exit+0xa57/0xa60
do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
System_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f


Kernel Offset: 0x0 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
drm_kms_helper: panic ocurred, switching back to text console
```

I have tried to fix grub with grub repair but after successfully doing that I've seen no change (the error stays the same).

When trying to boot manually following [these instructions](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorial...rub-2-on-linux), I get the following error:

```
Targeted filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty: Job control turned off
#
```

Note that when I write `ls` on the GRUB command line, I get partitions in the form of `(hd0,gpt9) -> sda9`

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST500LT012-9WS14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 2      525MB   567MB   41.9MB  fat32        Basic data partition          hidden
 3      567MB   701MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      701MB   1226MB  524MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 5      1226MB  395GB   394GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      395GB   395GB   1049kB  fat32                                      boot
 9      395GB   421GB   26.0GB  ext4                                       boot
10      421GB   487GB   65.3GB  ext4
 6      487GB   487GB   473MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 7      487GB   500GB   13.0GB  ntfs         Microsoft recovery partition  hidden, diag
```

```
Model: ATA LITEONIT LMT-32L (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  8589MB  8588MB                  Basic data partition
 2      8589MB  9613MB  1024MB  linux-swap(v1)
 3      9614MB  22.1GB  12.5GB  fat32                                 msftdata
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

Comment: Try booting from a live CD and then post the output of `sudo parted -l`. I am guessing your partitions have been renamed.

Comment: Mount your filesystems from a livecd and see if they are intact.  Either your root fs got corrupted, or it is no longer assigned the same partition number, and you have grub configured to refer to it by partition number, rather than by uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me to be an overlapping partition or a different kernel from the wrong partition loading

Answer (score 0):

If you started with sda9 @ 60GB / sda10 @ 7.7GB, and they're now (9) 26.0 / (10) 65.3, something has been seriously hosed. All I can recommend doing at this point is mounting each partition from the live CD and see what's left.

(`lsblk -f` will show the UUID's.)